# IntelliJ - how to run the main() - run always refer to the test folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have added junit test and have my set up as "src" and "test" separate. When I try to run, it always refer the test folder and execute the test. I made few changes later to src/main. How can I run the code in the main class. Do I need to change configuration to run main()

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to run main is to click play icon at left side as show in picture.

[image: Run Main java Intellj]

Also see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I was wondering why the green play icon was not displaying. I had the below line as 'public static main()' instead of

public static void main(String[] args)

I fixed this and I'm able to see the green icon to run the test. Thanks!

Comment: may be try making new project and check

Comment: use comment to reply